# Ask ProxyBroker to change proxy in serve mode

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, proxybroker

When I use ProxyBroker, for example, with this command line:

```
proxybroker serve --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 --types HTTPS --lvl High --countries US --strict
```

may occur situation, when proxy become bad, and you need to change it. For example, remote site show message to change IP.
Is there possibility to send message from python script to ProxyBroker to change proxy, or completely renew proxy list?